# 論文などに書かれているアルゴリズムをC/C++に変換するトランスレータはありませんか

Tags: アルゴリズム

論文に書かれているALGOLのような擬似コードを見るのですが、それを外形だけでもCやC++にしたいのですが、自分で打ち込むよりも手っ取り早く変換することができればより多くの論文を実行して読めると思いました。
擬似コードやALGOLをC/C++へ変換できる[トランスレータ](http://masudahp.web.fc2.com/cl/trans/trans00.html)はありませんか
FORTRANをCに変換するソフトウェアは有名ですがALGOLや擬似言語については見当たりませんでした。

Comment: ISO や IEEE などに pseudo code の規格があるわけでもありませんので、一口に pseudo code と言っても様々です。例えば、ですが、大昔には C のプリプロセッサを使って `#define IF if`, `#define THEN {`, `#define ELSE } else {`, `#define ENDIF }` などとする様なトランスレータ(?)モドキを見かけた事はあります。何の価値もないことですが。。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

疑似コードや論文にのってる抜粋のALGOLは、動いているFORTRANのソースとは別物で、根本的に実行に必要な情報が抜け落ちている物が多々ありますから、難しいかと思います。
自分ですぐに改変できるテストコードを沢山書くのが勉強にもなってよいでしょう。

データや実行のためのコードをgithubなどで公開する文化がもっと広まれば検証や改良が容易になって良いなとは思います。

Comment: ちょっと質問の趣旨からはズレていますが、ウォルフラムアルファというサービスは、数式を簡単に可視化したりできて面白かったです。